# Spock - extracting interactions to method

Tags: java, groovy, spock

The spock documentation points out that you can extract assertions of `then` block to other method and add `assert` keyword before each assertion.

I would also like to **extract interactions to helper method**. 
I tried wrapping interactions with `interaction` closure block but that did not work.

Is it possible? If it is how to achieve it?

Comment: It's rather not possible. Can you prepare a SSCCE?

Answer (score 27):

Turns out you can. You have to wrap helper method call with interaction:

```
then:
    interaction {
         helperMethod()
    }
```

and then you can put interactions in a helper method like that:

```
def helperMethod() {
    1 * someObj.getInt() >> 2
}
```

I did it other way around (wrapped helper method body in interaction), that's why it did not work

Comment: You should accept your own answer since it's correct :)